# INNER JOIN on broken table (non-nullable field)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

I have three tables:

```
Document                     DocumentExt           Tracking
-------------------------    -----------------     --------------------------------------------
ID  |  Name   |   DocType    DocId  |  OtherId     ID  |  DocOtherId  |  DocType  |  AccessTime
-------------------------    -----------------     --------------------------------------------   
1      SomeDoc    Z          1         Doc1        1      Doc2           X          [Date here]
2      SomeDoc2   X          2         Doc2        2                     A          [Date here]
3      SomeDoc3   Y          3         Doc3        3      Doc1           Z          [Date here]
...    ...        ...        ...       ...         ...    ...            ...        ...
```

Note the missing value in `Tracking.DocOtherId`.  This is a non-nullable field and defaults to an empty string.

The problem is that I need to perform a join on these two that includes *one row for each record in `Tracking`*, but also the associated information from `Document`.  Such like:

```
SELECT 
    Tracking.ID, Document.Name 
FROM 
    Tracking
INNER JOIN 
    DocumentExt ON DocumentExt.OtherId = Tracking.DocOtherId
INNER JOIN 
    Document ON Document.ID = DocumentExt.DocId
```

However, since `Tracking.DocOtherId` in non-nullable, the query is returning a row for each of the records in `DocumentExt` AND `Tracking`. I need it to treat `Tracking.DocOtherId` as nullable for the purposes of the query so that the JOIN will work properly. Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**:  I suppose I need to make it clear that I need *ONE* record returned for *EACH* record in `Tracking`, including the ones with the empty string in `DocOtherId`.

For example:

```
TrackingId  |  DocumentName
---------------------------
1              SomeDoc2
2              NULL
3              SomeDoc1
...            ...
```

**EDIT 2**: Flagged for closure.  I went about this all wrong and I've taken an entirely different approach.

Comment: cant you add a where clause saying WHERE Tracking.DocOtherId <> ''?

Comment: Is the ID column across all three tables the same? If you get another Tracking entry on SomeDoc will it still have an ID in Tracking of 1?

Comment: 1. Why is DocOtherId a non-nullable field if there are so many empty strings? 2. is your data set so large that it would be prohibitive to just create a temp table with the tracking data where docotherid is not null?

Comment: @Asdfg, No, I can't, unfortunately.  Because there is no record in `DocumentExt` with an empty string value, there's no comparison to be made for an empty string.  Adding such a record could have disastrous consequences for the database as a whole.

Comment: @rhealitycheck, 1) that's only one of the many many horrible problems our database has.  2) I haven't considered the temp table approach.  I'll look into that.  Could you possibly provide an example?

Comment: Perhaps if you added expected output you might get an answer. As it stands its unclear what you expect or why a LEFT JOIN wouldn't work for you.

Comment: I agree with Conrad. It doesn't even make a difference wether there is '' or NULL in DocOtherId, because *both* have no match in DocumentExt, right? So what is the problem actually?

Comment: Updated question to include example result.

Comment: Wouldn't simply adding distinct to the query with the left join solve this problem? It seems to me like you just want the distinct values for each of the tracking ids, is that correct?

Comment: @rhealitycheck, `DISTINCT` does nothing.  And neither does changing the type of `JOIN`.  I'm so totally lost on this one.  :/

Comment: @StephenCollins so I created a SQLFiddle -  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2af75/1. See if you can't modify the schema in there to give us a better idea of what's going on with your data and what you are seeing. That could help us help you.

Comment: You need to use Left Join instead of Inner join: Replace INNER JOIN  DocumentExt to LEFT JOIN DocumentExt

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not significantly large, you can try using a temp table to strip your data and then do a join on that refined data. For example:

**EDIT: to respond to the first comment below**

this first section will get you the temp table you need without the empty strings and instead have nulls where the empty strings would be

```
Select ID, 
     case when DocOtherId = '' then null else DocOtherId end,
     AccessTime
     into #tracking
From Tracking
```

then use this temp table to join back to your data the same way you had originally. in this example you just sub out #tracking for Tracking, though you can call your temp table anything you want.

```
SELECT 
    Tracking.ID, Document.Name 
FROM 
    #tracking
INNER JOIN 
    DocumentExt ON DocumentExt.OtherId = Tracking.DocOtherId
INNER JOIN 
    Document ON Document.ID = DocumentExt.DocId
```

Comment: Simply adding `WHERE Tracking.DocOtherId <> ''` would accomplish the same thing.  The problem with this approach is that it excludes the `Tracking` record with the `ID` of 2 from the query (or any others where the `DocOtherId` is an empty string.)  I need ALL of the records from `Tracking` included.

Comment: Well an alternative is to not exclude all the blank strings but to turn it into a nullable field in the temp table. I'll update my response with both cases so you can see what I mean (it's easier to see the code in the answer than a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I saw this comment:

> I need ALL of the records from Tracking included.

That means you want an **OUTER** join, not an INNER join. Use the coalesce() function to show a generic value for missing names.

```
 SELECT Tracking.ID, coalesce(Document.Name,'') As Name
 FROM Tracking t
 LEFT JOIN DocumentExt de ON de.OtherID = t.DocOtherId
 LEFT JOIN Document d on d.ID = de.DocID
```

This will return *ONE* record for *EACH* record in the tracking table, including the ones with the empty string in DocOtherId.

Comment: I don't need to return NULLs or empty strings.  I need the empty strings treated as nulls for the JOIN operation.

Comment: @StephenCollins I actually am going to agree with Joel here. Even if you had nulls in your original table, you would need a left join to get everything from Tracking to show up. If you use an inner join it will essentially get rid of any of the blank strings/nulls in your Tracking table. Can you post an example of the results you want to get?

Comment: @Stephen Collins: How is this different from the desired results you just posted? Joel thinks you need outer joins, Conrad thinks so, I do, but you keep telling us no. Then you say you don't want any NULLS in your results, but then you post a desired result list with NULLS in it. What the heck?